# How to run sql script file using JDBI

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I am using jdbi to make connection to db and execute sql command.

```
dbi = new DBI("jdbc:mysql://"+dbHostName+"/"+dbName, "root", "");
    dbi.withHandle(new HandleCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object withHandle(Handle handle) throws Exception {
            handle.execute("Query to execute")
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Now i want to run sql file using jdbi. I googled a lot but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Read here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html and replace "Query to execute"' by what you read.

Answer (score 8):

You should read your sql file to string and then execute it like

```
String script = ".. your sql file contents here ..";
try (Handle h = dbi.open()) {
    h.createScript(script).execute();
}
```

Comment: ... this doesn't actually work. It interprets the SQL and sometimes it breaks. For example on Oracle it gives error if your SQL contains stuff like trigger definitions with multiple statements...